# Convert decimal to double returns scientific notation

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I am reading data from an Excel file and the data value and the value is 0.0000000001. When it is read from C# the value is returned as 1E-10. The cell value is `row.Cells[2].Value = 1E-10`

I tried from other posts to first convert to a decimal:

```
decimal h1 = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

and here `h1 = 0.0000000001` as expected.

I need the value to be in double so I then did:

```
Double val1 = Decimal.ToDouble(h1);
```

But `val1` is now back to 1E-10

How can I keep the value as double = 0.0000000001?

Please test the following snippet of code to illustrate what the issue is:

decimal t1 = Decimal.Parse("1E-10", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
Double t2 = Convert.ToDouble(t1);

You will see t1 = .0000000001 and t2 = 1E-10

Comment: you can't *keep* `double` as `0.0000000001`, but you can *represent*: `Console.Write(val.ToString("f10"));` here `f10` format means "with 10 digits after the decimal point"

Comment: But I need to pass a double value to a class. I don't really care about what it looks like.

Comment: well, `0.0000000001 == 1e-10` (`1e-10` is `1` multiplied by `10` in `-10`th power) so you can do nothing; both values *are equal*

Comment: I understand that but the down steam system cannot handle 1E-10. There must be some solution.

Comment: Please, provide more info: what does "down steam system cannot handle 1E-10" means? Do you a have an exception (which and where) thrown, incorrect result, something else?

Comment: I have a class where this data field is of type double so I need to fill in data of type double. When I do it is 1E-10 which it cannot handle.

Comment: I think you're confusing how a double _looks_ when displayed and what the _actual_ value is.

Comment: When I fill the class with the double value it sends 1E-10.

Comment: Try the small snippet of code in my question and you will what I mean.

Comment: 1E-10 is a valid double value.  Internally doubles are binary regardless of the value stored and is not stored as a string'.   If the class is having trouble with 1E-10, then it is likely converting the double to a string at some point without specifying the format or simply has an issue with small numbers.  You can always display the double as 0.0000000001 with the correct parameters passed to ToString() as noted by Dmitry

Comment: Please see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`1E-10` is the same as `0.0000000001`

I have not tested it but maybe this will help:

`string variable = $"{val1:N10}";`

Comment: I don't need a string. I need the decimal (which is correct) that when I cast to a double to not be 1E-10 but like the decimal value .0000000001

Answer (score 0):

Use the default conversion class

```
 Double val1 = Convert.ToDouble(h1)
```

And convert to string to represent the full number

```
Console.WriteLine(h1.toString("F10"))
```

Where F10 it's the decimales format what you want

Comment: I'm not interested in have the correct string value.

Comment: Please try the following:                     decimal t1 = Decimal.Parse("1E-10", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
                    Double t2 = Convert.ToDouble(priceConvert);